# How to send the AKS application logs to Log Analytics workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, istio, istio-gateway

I have created an AKS cluster using the following Terraform code

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = var.virtual_network_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  address_space       = [var.virtual_network_address_prefix]

  subnet {
    name           = var.aks_subnet_name
    address_prefix = var.aks_subnet_address_prefix
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "kubesubnet" {
  name                 = var.aks_subnet_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  depends_on           = [azurerm_virtual_network.test]
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
  name       = var.aks_name
  location   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  dns_prefix = var.aks_dns_prefix

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  http_application_routing_enabled = false

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = var.vm_user_name

    ssh_key {
      key_data = file(var.public_ssh_key_path)
    }
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name            = "agentpool"
    node_count      = var.aks_agent_count
    vm_size         = var.aks_agent_vm_size
    os_disk_size_gb = var.aks_agent_os_disk_size
    vnet_subnet_id  = data.azurerm_subnet.kubesubnet.id
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = local.client_id
    client_secret = local.client_secret
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = "azure"
    dns_service_ip     = var.aks_dns_service_ip
    docker_bridge_cidr = var.aks_docker_bridge_cidr
    service_cidr       = var.aks_service_cidr
  }

  # Enabled the cluster configuration to the Azure kubernets with RBAC
  azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control { 
    managed                     = var.azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control_managed
    admin_group_object_ids      = var.active_directory_role_based_access_control_admin_group_object_ids
    azure_rbac_enabled          = var.azure_rbac_enabled
  }

  oms_agent {
    log_analytics_workspace_id  = module.log_analytics_workspace[0].id
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    delete = "20m"
  }  

  depends_on = [data.azurerm_subnet.kubesubnet,module.log_analytics_workspace]
  tags       = var.tags
}
```

and followed the below steps and installed the ISTIO as per the [ISTIO documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/helm/)

```
#Prerequisites
helm repo add istio https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
helm repo update

#create namespace
kubectl create namespace istio-system

# helm install istio-base and istiod
helm install istio-base istio/base -n istio-system
helm install istiod istio/istiod -n istio-system --wait

# Check the installation status
helm status istiod -n istio-system

#create namespace and enable istio-injection for envoy proxy containers
kubectl create namespace istio-ingress
kubectl label namespace istio-ingress istio-injection=enabled

## helm install istio-ingress for traffic management
helm install istio-ingress istio/gateway -n istio-ingress --wait

## Mark the default namespace as istio-injection=enabled
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled

## Install the App and Gateway
kubectl apply -f bookinfo.yaml
kubectl apply -f bookinfo-gateway.yaml
```

and I could access the application like shown below

[image]

This application prints the logs in the console.

I have created the Log Analytics workspace as mentioned below

```
# Create Log Analytics Workspace
module "log_analytics_workspace" {
  source                = "./modules/log_analytics_workspace"
  count                 = var.enable_log_analytics_workspace == true ? 1 : 0
  app_or_service_name   = "log" 
  subscription_type     = var.subscription_type 
  environment           = var.environment 
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name 
  location              = var.location 
  instance_number       = var.instance_number  
  sku                   = var.log_analytics_workspace_sku
  retention_in_days     = var.log_analytics_workspace_retention_in_days 
  tags                  = var.tags
}
```

and set the **log_anaglytics_workspace_id** in the **oms_agent** section in azurerm_kubernetes_cluster to collect logs and ship to Log Analytics.

Is that all needed to ship the application logs to Log Analytics Workspace? somehow I don't see the logs flowing? am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/monitor-aks#level-4--applications) can help.